# Particle System Packs for SceneKit / Xcode?

Tags: scenekit, particle-system

Is anyone aware of some pre-built particle system emitter collections / packs for SceneKit / Xcode? I.e. .scnp particle files.  Free or professional, I just want some pre built options with images to play with.

I am able to find a bunch of packs for Unity and Unreal, but not Xcode Particle Emitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to create your own basic particle systems. This site explains the basics of creating a new particle system by modifying the particle systems built in:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/128745/scene-kit-tutorial-swift-part-5-particle-systems

Answer (score 0):

Scene Kit doesn't have many users. Those few that do use it seem to be very busy using it, and trying to figure out how to use it. So the answer is "no, there are no emitter packs and presets (beyond what's built in) for Scene Kit".